# How to download multiple files of firebase Storage Android?

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I am downloading files from firebase storage
But I can only download one by one
Can I download multiple files at once?
Is it the best way to repeat the same code?

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
StorageReference islandRef = storageRef.child(filename);

final String saveFilename = filename;
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/down/");

// If no folders
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}

final File localFile = new File(dir,saveFilename);


islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        

    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call putFile once for each file you want to download.  You will need a different reference and local file for each call.

```
FileDownloadTask task1 = storageRef1.getFile(localFile1);
FileDownloadTask task2 = storageRef2.getFile(localFile3);
FileDownloadTask task3 = storageRef3.getFile(localFile3);
```

You can then wait for all them to complete with [Tasks.whenAll()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAll(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)):

```
Tasks.whenAll(task1, task2, task3)
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Task<*>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Task task) {
        

    }
})
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific API to download multiple files. You'll just have to download them by calling the same API for each file.